# XF Android project does not build after adding Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material nuget

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project and now I'd like to improve it with the new Visual / Material features.

On IOS, it works like a charm.

On Android I have strange problems: after adding Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material nuget I get weird error messages and my project does not build:

```
\res\values\values.xml(6): error APT0000: Attribute "statusBarBackground" already defined with incompatible format.
\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
\res\values\values.xml(10): error APT0000: Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
\res\values\values.xml(17): error APT0000: Attribute "layout_insetEdge" already defined with incompatible format.
\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
\res\values\values.xml(17): error APT0000: Attribute "layout_dodgeInsetEdges" already defined with incompatible format.
\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
\res\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar'.
\res\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'materialButtonStyle'.
\res\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.MaterialComponents.Button'.
\res\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton'.
\res\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox'.
\res\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'boxCollapsedPaddingTop'.
```

I use Visual Studio 2017 Professional on Windows, I don't use any prerelease nuget.

Xamarin.Forms version is 3.6.0.293080.
Minimum Android API level is 21, target is 28, and compiled with 28.
Xamarin Android support libraries version is 28.0.0.1.

I tried the usual tricks (delete bin, obj dir, restart Visual Studio, run it in admin mode, delete Xamarin app data...) but neither helped.

The same thing happens if I create a new project from schratch, and don't do anything with it, just add visual.material nuget to the Android project.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this what you are using? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material/4.0.0.169046-pre5?

Comment: I use Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material, NOT pre-relase, but the stable one (3.6.0.293080). Now up to your suggestion I tried also the latest pre-relase, but it does not fix the bug.

Comment: Did you try getting rid of resource designer and letting it regenerate?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What should I get rid of, Thx!

Comment: The `ResourceDesigner.cs`  delete it once rebuild then readd it to project and see what happens

Comment: The same errors...

Comment: if you still use old packages.config, make sure you always see same monodroid in hint path and don't mix 81 with 90

Comment: Thx magicandre1981, you lead me to the right direction. Pls. add it as an answer and I will accept it! Thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue a few days ago where I first had TargetFramework set to Android 8.1, installed same packages and later changed it to Android9 and installed a new package.

The Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material requires Android 9 to be set in Android project options and you previously had 8.1 configured and installed nuget packages for Android 8.1.

If you still use old [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) like me to add NuGet packages, make sure you always see same monodroid string in hint path in the csproj and don't mix 81 with 90 and always have **monoandroid90**.

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material , Version=3.6.0.293080, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
     <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.Material.3.6.0.293080\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Forms.Material.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

After changing TargetFramework to 9, open [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell#opening-the-console-and-console-controls) and run

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies
```

to let VS update the packages.config and csproj.

Comment: Just a side note: This answer fix issues happening while csproj has a mix of monoandroid81 and monoandroid90, which covers many other situations apart from the original question.

Comment: @xleon which issue do you had?

Comment: Same errors as the question but I´m not using Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material 
Your answer fixed all issues I had

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am having same issues when adding Xamarin.KeyboardHelper library to my Xamarin.forms project on Visual Studio 2017.  It requires Target Framework to be set to 9.0.  I added the nuget and set the Target Framework from 8.1 to 9.0 but I still have this exact issue on Android.  Any suggestion?  Thanks

Comment: @pixel look in the csproj that the hint path is always monoandroid90

Comment: @magicandre1981 I see nothing with "hint" in it in droid.csproj file (VS2017)

Comment: @pixel the hintpath is only in the csproj if you still use the old packages.config way to install nuget packages.

Comment: Cool! Spent some time but that worth it:
1. Open *.csproj file and replace all "monoandroid81" to "monoandroid90" (I did for HintPath and Import tags)
2. Delete obj/bin, clean packages folder, restart VS
3. Compile. It may say that some packages are missing. Revert changes back for those: put back "monoandroidXX" which was there before your changes.
4. Delete obj/bin, clean packages folder, restart VS

Comment: 5. Run the app. If you see "java.exe exited with code 2" compilation error - turn Multi-Dex on.

Comment: Thanks, Solved my problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on github:

Migrating Package.json File to PackageReference to resolved problem.

1 - Click right on packages.config in Android Project

2 - Click on Migration Package.config to PackageReference

3 - Accept

4 - Run Project

Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5828

I also updated references with Nuget, done a clean, removed obj and bin fonder, and then Build.