# Android Build Failed after updating Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

After updating Xamarin.forms to version 3.6, Android build is failing. Getting errors like :

> Error APT0000: Attribute "statusBarBackground" already defined with
>   incompatible format. (APT0000)  Error APT0000: Attribute
>   "layout_insetEdge" already defined with incompatible format. (APT0000)
>   Project/Droid/obj/Debug/lp/47/jl/res/values/values.xml(0,0): Error
>   APT0000: Original attribute defined here. (APT0000)

Version of Xamarin.Forms are same in all projects.
Already tried removing bin /obj. Did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XF Android project does not build after adding Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55523996/xf-android-project-does-not-build-after-adding-xamarin-forms-visual-material-nug)

Comment: [check csproj for hint path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55552972/1466046) and make sure the path is all the same version monodroid81 for example and don't mix them

Comment: @Mili did you find a solution?